# Why while using makefile I receive undefined reference error?

Tags: c, makefile, undefined-reference

I created the following makefile:

```
assembler: main.o first_pass.o second_pass.o helpers.o data_array.o symbol_table.o
            gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic main.o first_pass.o second_pass.o helpers.o data_array.o symbol_table.o -o assembler
main.o:         main.c header.h
                gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic main.c -o main.o
first_pass.o:   first_pass.c header.h
                gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic first_pass.c -o first_pass.o
second_pass.o:  second_pass.c header.h
                gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic second_pass.c -o second_pass.o
helpers.o:      helpers.c header.h data.h
                gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic helpers.c -o helpers.o
data_array.o:   data_array.c header.h data.h
                gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic data_array.c -o data_array.o
symbol_table.o: symbol_table.c header.h data.h
                gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic symbol_table.c -o symbol_table.o
```

In my 'main.c' file I have `#include "header.h"`. Where in 'header.h' I have the declarations of all the functions.
But I receive the following error:

```
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic main.c -o main.o
/tmp/cc3dP7hx.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x257): undefined reference to `first_pass`
main.c:(.text+0x2e4): undefined reference to `second_pass'
main.c:(.text+0x37f): undefined reference to build_obj_file
main.c:(.text+0x3a9): undefined reference to build_ent_file
main.c:(.text+0x427): undefined reference to free_all_data
main.c:(.text+0x436): undefined reference to free_all_symbols
main.c:(.text+0x44d): undefined reference to free_all_words
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:4: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Your `main` target should depend on all of the other objects

Comment: Also double check that you are creating Deps files with gcc to make sure it handles h file build order and such correctly.

Comment: You should be using the `-c` option to make `.o` files. Otherwise it's trying to make an executable file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your command doesn't create object files, but attempt to build executable programs:

> ```
> gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic main.c -o main.o
> ```

You need the `-c` option to create object files:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic main.c -c -o main.o
```

---

A better idea would be to rely on the `make` [*implicit rules*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#toc-Using-Implicit-Rules) so you don't have to explicitly list all commands:

```
CC = gcc
LD = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic
LDFLAGS =

assembler: main.o first_pass.o second_pass.o helpers.o data_array.o symbol_table.o
```

You might want to add rules for the header-file dependencies, or figure out some way to auto-generate them (it's possible). Other than that the above `Makefile` should be enough to build all object files and then link them together into the `assembler` executable program.

Note that I have removed the `-ansi` flag, as it's mostly obsolete these days.

Comment: The `-o filename.o` arguments aren't needed if the `.c` and `.o` files have the same root name, which they do.

Comment: Also, the `.h` file dependencies will be lost if there aren't entries for the individual `.o` files.  If `header.h` or `data.h` change, what will trigger recompilation of the appropriate `.o` files?